# What is the best way to troubleshoot an web app having JavaScript, HTML, Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-apps-script

I have a web app project for form submission with multiple dependable selections options. The form has some distance calculating function and calculating the distance from the user's location to outlets of the city selected in the form. My form was working just fine. And then I edit some code and now form options in selection elements are not coming. What is the best method used for troubleshooting code?

I do not like help to pinpoint errors in code, rather I am asking what is the best way to troubleshoot the code having HTML, javascript, and apps script? it seems I am finding this is happening to me again and again.

Answer (score 1):

The general way of debugging errors in your script is to check `My Executions` in `script.google.com` and checking the Cloud Logs on the execution you want:

**Sample:**

[image]

To display debug logs you would want to put `console.log()` lines on key points in your code to display the values of key variables.

**Sample:**

[image]

It's generally better to do debugging by manually running the script from GAS, before deployment as web app.

Also, HTML errors are a bit harder to debug as you only have the output page to check.

**Reference:**

[Troubleshooting in Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)